# React: Siblings in a list must have unique key. Do the children of these list siblings need them too?

Tags: reactjs, key

I am generating a series of divs by using `.map()` on my state (created via the `useState()` React hook).

Each of these divs has a unique React `key`. However, I still receive the following error:

```
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
```

Each of these `<div>` siblings has 30-50 children. Does each of those children need a unique React `key` as well?

---

The React documentation (https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) appears ambiguous on this point.

It indicates that:

- "A good rule of thumb is that elements inside the map() call need keys." (All elements? Or just the parent siblings?)
- Keys must only be unique among siblings. (The scenario I describe follows this rule)

However none of its examples provide clarity on list siblings with many nested elements within.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: This might be helpful to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329382/understanding-unique-keys-for-array-children-in-react-js

Answer (score 0):

every time when you are rendering any series of nodes(React.Fragment, div, span etc) in loop like bellow you must have to do:

```
const list = [...list of your raw items]; // Array<{id: number, name: string}>

return (
  <main>
    {list.map((item, index) => (
      <section key={item.id}>
        <div><span>{item.name}</span></div>
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
)
```

1. define `key` for top-level node element inside map callback(in my example it is `section`);
2. key should be an uniq parameter within current loop, it can be `index` but it is not recommended(for better performance in case if you dynamically modify `list`). Usually it is an ID of each entity;

ps. You do not have to pass down `key` for any children(in my example - `div` and `span`), but it is not harmful tho(just useless).